# Ubuntu 13.04 wake up hibernate suspend black display on Nokia Booklet 3G

Tags: 13.04, suspend, hibernate, 3g

Lubuntu 13.04 runs amazing on the Nokia Booklet 3G with a SSD, the only issue I got is the wake up/suspend/hibernate not working properly i.e. the display stays blank or black. Any idea how to fix it? Lubuntu 12.10 had no such issues.\
Thanks a mil.

Answer (score 0):

Try experimenting the arguments of pm-suspend, for example:

```
pm-suspend --quirk-radeon-off
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried lots of different options myself. In the end updating to a new mainline kernel solved it for me. I updated to kernel 3.11 and so far things are working ok. Disclaimer: something else might break but at least suspend now works super duper fast.

I used this mainline kernel update script from [UpUbuntu](http://www.upubuntu.com/2013/09/installupgrade-to-linux-kernel-311.html):

```
cd /tmp
wget http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47950494/upubuntu/kernel-3.11 -O kernel-3.11
chmod +x kernel-3.11
sudo sh kernel-3.11
sudo reboot
```