# How to check what suspends? Lubuntu saucy

Tags: lubuntu, power-management, suspend, xfce4-power-manager

I have a Nokia Booklet 3G and I have a problem (not one, actually) with Poulsbo suspend/resume.
I installed Lubuntu saucy (beta), which runs smoother than previous versions (it actually boots, unlike Lubuntus and Ubuntus earlier than 12.10).

When everything in `xfce4-power-manager` is set to "nothing" (closing the lid, low power, pressing buttons etc.) and `--quirk-vbemode-restore` is added to `/etc/pm/cinfig.d/`  (as suggested here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo) computer suspends successfully, and shuts down after pressing power button.
But when I change to anything other than "none", system crashes on resume.

What actually puts my system to sleep when power manager is set to "do nothing"?

Comment: mm... can you separate the questions please? As it is currently is difficult to address all your questions at the same time.

Comment: You're right. I moved one of the questions here: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/346531/lubuntu-xfce4-power-manager-alternative).

Comment: See this answer for fixing the suspend/resume: http://askubuntu.com/a/351509/13744