# Lubuntu - xfce4-power-manager alternative

Tags: lubuntu, power-management, battery, xfce4-power-manager

Can I uninstall `xfce4-power-manager` and set my suspend settings somewhere else?
How would I be able to check my battery status?

I would like to get rid of `xfce4-power-manager` because of my problems with suspend/resume on a Nokia Booklet 3G. Further description and another question here: [How to check what suspends? Lubuntu saucy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346395/how-to-check-what-suspends-lubuntu-saucy)

I have `xfce4-notifyd` installed.

Comment: Do you have xfce4-notifyd installed?